# Sort entries in list by timestamp included in names of the entry in python

Tags: python

I am new into programming and want to sort the entries in my list `allIetsDatalight` by timestamp included in names of the entry. So I put all the files, which have following namestructure `125_L_2020-11-12_12-08-35.IV2`, of my `path` with the ending `.IV2` in the list `allIetsDatalight` and now I want to sort all entries.
Another problem is, that the first 6 characters of my filename `125_L_` always changes from file to file.
I struggling since two days two find something in the internet, but i couldn´f find something right for my program.

My Program:

```
import os, sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

path = 'C:\\\Users\\\simon'

allIetsDatalight = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.IV2')]

for f in allIetsData:
    if f == 'advIV.summary':
        allIetsData.remove(f)

    if f == 'darkIV.summary':
        allIetsData.remove(f)

    if f == 'lightIV.summary':
        allIetsData.remove(f)

for iets in ietsToPlot:
    Cellnumberlight, Celllight, Pixellight, Grouplight, Descriptionlight, Typelight, Illuminationdirectionlight, ScanDirectionlight, Voltagelight, Currentlight, Jlight, Timelight, PCElight =[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

    f = open(path +"\\" + allIetsDatalight[iets])
    data = f.readlines()
    i =0
    for l in data:
        x = l.split()  
        if i == 3:
            Pixellight.append(str(x[1])) 
            Pixellight1 = str(Pixellight)[1:-1]
        if i == 4:
            Grouplight.append(str(x[1]))
            Grouplight1 = str(Grouplight)[2:-2] 
        if i == 5:
            Descriptionlight.append(str(x[1]))
            Descriptionlight1 = str(Descriptionlight)[1:-1]
        if i == 8:
            Typelight.append(str(x[1]))
            Typelight1 = str(Typelight)[1:-1]
        if i == 11:
            ScanDirectionlight.append(str(x[1]))
            ScanDirectionlight1 = str(ScanDirectionlight)[1:-1]
        if i == 27:
            PCElight.append(float(x[1]))
        if i > 33:
            Voltagelight.append(float(x[0]))
            Jlight.append(float(x[2]))
        i +=1 

    for m in Grouplight1:
        while int(m) > b:
            plt.figure()
            b +=1
    print(Grouplight1)

    plt.plot(Voltagelight, Jlight, linewidth=2, label= "Batchnr.: %s %s; Pixel: %s; direction: %s; lightsource: %s" % (Descriptionlight1.replace("'", ""), Grouplight1.replace("'", ""), Pixellight1.replace("'", ""), ScanDirectionlight1.replace("'", ""), Typelight1.replace("'", "")))

    plt.title('JV-Measurement', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlim(-0.5,1.25)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('Voltage in V ', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('J in mA/cm^2', fontsize=18)  

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to search for a complete solution to your very specific problem. You need to break down your task to small atomic operations and then it will be easier to find solutions online. For example, it sounds like you can search for `how to custom sort a list` and `how to search for a specific pattern in a string`. You will not find a solution for your specific problem, but you can combine solutions for your different tasks

Comment: Also you should post a [mre]. There are some undefined variable's in your code which makes it harder to understand and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with this:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

example = ["125_L_2021-11-12_12-08-35.IV2", "15_LA_2020-11-12_12-08-35.IV2", "1A25_%_2019-11-12_12-08-35.IV2"]

example.sort(key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}', x).group(0), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))

for element in example:
    print(element)
```

and the output will be:

```
1A25_%_2019-11-12_12-08-35.IV2
15_LA_2020-11-12_12-08-35.IV2
125_L_2021-11-12_12-08-35.IV2
```

As you can see, no matter what pattern the names have before the date (I tried to modify them with different characters and lengths), in the end they are all correctly ordered. The important thing is that the pattern in which the date is written does not change unless the regular expression also changes accordingly.

The solution is very concise and perhaps unclear due to the use of nested functions, I try to explain:
the first thing that the one-line function does is to search with a regular expression the pattern with which the date is written (`YYYY-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss`). Once the date is found, it is converted to `datatime`. All this done within the lambda function in the sort function allows you to sort the whole list.

Obviously you can divide that function into sub-instructions, but the concept is this.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a million. I am so happy and I even understood your code (at least I think so).

Comment: @Simon123457 I'm glad it worked out. To make the code clearer you could create a temporary dictionary (or a list of lists, or list of tuples) containing the original name and date and sort it by date, but I looked for the most concise solution possible.
Meanwhile, if you could mark the answer as solved would be great!